# How can I swap images on button click?

Tags: java, android, android-imagebutton

Essentially All the ImageButton has to do (InactiveButton) is switch to an image when pressed. I have no clue where to start with this because I am new to Android Studio.

I have tried using the selector class but I don't know what it's supposed to accomplish. When I use other's code such as public void buttonOnClick(View v), android studio says it's deprecated?

XML layout:

```xml
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/InactiveButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/button_default" />
```

EDIT 1: I have added the following code and still got an *"annotations are not allowed here"* @override on line 52, and *cannot resolve symbol v* on line 53.

[Picture of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOciu.png)

**EDIT 2: Image of final error on line 50**

[Location of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOciu.png)

[Actual Compiler Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9u874.png)

Comment: One other suggestion if your all margin is of same dp then you can directly use layout_margin = "8dp" and it will work the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Ferran has said is absolutely right.

You need to implement it in correct way.

Firstly define you image view before onCreate method so that it will be treated as global variable and advantage of this is you can use it anywhere in same activity.
Like 
`ImageButton inactiveButton;`

Secondly, find its view by using FindViewById in onCreate method.
Like 
`inactiveButton = convertView.findViewById(R.id.InactiveButton);`

Next, you can implement onClickListener on inactiveButton by using two ways:
1. You can implement "implements View.OnClickListener" to your activity by using inactiveButton.setOnClickListener(this); This will prompt you to implement "android.view.View.OnClickListener" to your activity or fragment. Implement this method this will add onClick method and here you can write you code to change image in the image button

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
          // add this, this will help you to implement multiple clicklisteners and you can add different methods in each click listener
        switch (v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.InactiveButton:
                 inactiveButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.otherimage);
                break;
            default:break;
        }
    }
```

[image: first way]

2. You can directly write OnClickListener, you need to keep this in main method

```
     inactiveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                       inactiveButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.otherimage); 
                    }
                });
```

[image: second way]

Hope this will help you. I know I have added a lot of information but I think it will help you in long run. You can check images for more clarity then you can easily understad you flaw.

Regards
Amanpreet

Answer (score 0):

You can change the image like this:

```java
ImageView someImageView= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.some_image_view);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.some_image);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `onCreate` method from your `Activity`

```
ImageButton inactiveButton = convertView.findViewById(R.id.InactiveButton);
```

Now, you have a reference to your `ImageView`.

Then, you need to define what to do when you click on it.

```
    inactiveButton .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // put here the code when ImageView is clicked

            // to change the ImageView image  
            inactiveButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.otherimage);
        }
    });
```

That's all.

Comment: Hey I tried adding your code to the mainactivity java and I get got some errors I don't know how to fix. I'll post what it looks like above.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. Your button is `ImageButton` and not `ImageView`. Please change this on the first line and try. I have edited my answer...